# Могу ли я считать и записать определенную строку?

Tags: python, файлы

Мне нужно записать в файл три параметра так,чтобы они сохранялись даже при закрытии. Также по ходу программы содержимое этого файла будет меняться. Можно ли в питоне построить примерно следующее :

В файле уже записаны, допустим, 3 параметра которые я юзаю, причем каждый с новой строки :

(Примерное содержимое)
Param_1

Param_2

Param_3

Вот, допустим мне понадобилось считать или перезаписать Param_2. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Есть ответ на английском: [What's the best practice using a settings file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5055042/2913477)

Comment: @MiniMax -  а причем тут файл конфигурации  к общему вопросу чтения-модификации файла?

Comment: @passant Да, не в тему :)

Comment: Получается, файл должен использоваться как база данных?

Comment: Файл должен использоваться как файл -  место энергонезависимого, долговременного хранения данных.

Answer (score 0):

1. Открываете файл на чтение.
2. Считываете весь файл в память.
3. Закрываете файл.
4. Изменяете строчку.
5. Открываете файл на запись.
6. Перезаписываете весь файл на внешнюю память.
7. Закрываете файл.